# Adapting the Balanced payment library to code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, balanced-payments

I'm working on setting up Balanced Payments with my code igniter application. This is the github repo for the php code for Balanced. I'm wondering if anybody knows how to make this implementation?

https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php

Comment: Can you paste a link to your github repository? It should be very similar to how you integrate any 3rd party service. What's your exact use case?

Comment: It's a private repo at the moment. Basically, I'm pretty new to CI and very new to Balanced. I will need to create customers and add bank accounts and credit accounts to that customer. Debit cards associated to customers, credit bank accounts associated to customers, etc.